# Android Moodstocks image recognition error

Tags: android, image, image-processing

Hello everybody I'm using Moodstrocks API in my application where it has an image recognition. When I followed the example [here](https://moodstocks.com/documentation/getting-started/android/) and ran the app, I'm getting error code 2 which is Invalid use of library. I don't know why I'm getting this error I already imported the libraries and followed the tutorial well. Do you know what could be the mistake I did in here? Your help will truly be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work at Moodstocks.

Most of the time, the "invalid use of the library" error comes from the fact that you are trying to perform operations on a `Scanner` object that has not been opened, or that has already been closed. Bear in mind that the `Scanner` **must** remain opened all along the use of the Moodstocks SDK.

So I guess you should check that the `open` method has worked as expected, and that the Activity holding the `Scanner` is not prematurely destroyed.

If that doesn't solve the issue, please contact us directly at support@moodstocks.com, we'll be happy to help you.